# Как вы считаете, насколько светлое будущее ожидает JavaScript и почему?

Tags: node.js, javascript, qooxdoo

И еще подвопрос: 
Есть ли будущее у `node.js, qooxdoo` и прочих интересных вещей.

Answer (score 3):

По поводу javascript в целом - будущее ждет светлое ( собственно если отбросить IE уже сейчас все замечательно ). Все браузеры ведут извечную борьбу за скорость работы javascript ( что является огромным плюсом ). Да что говорить, взгляните хотя-бы на WebGL ( да технология еще не устоялась и не факт что устоится, но тем не менее ), кто бы мог предположить что, из языка, по сути, исключительно для простых манипуляций с DOM'ом ( к слову и они выполнялись не быстро ) получиться скриптовый язык дающий возможность писать 3d приложения в браузере =)

Да и выбора у JS нет, это основной клиентский язык веба и с тем, на каком он уровне на данный момент - с трудом представляю себе ему замену ( да и смысл. И даже если бы это происходило, длилось бы это десятилетиями )

У node.js будущее есть т.к. технология сильно поддерживается со стороны microsoft( с их стороны, в какой-то степени, даже пропагандируется ) и разработчиков, по поводу qooxdoo  - не знаю.

[@Павел Зайцев](/users/1789/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B2) - смогут ли они продолжать конкурировать с **другими** схожими технологиями?

Я так понимаю это что касаемо nodejs и qooxdoo? Просто в контексте JS читается странно, у JS нет конкурентов =)

Comment: Кстати про js, давайте не будем забывать про dart, созданный как замена js. Будущее js на прямую зависит от успешности данного проекта и от маркетинга корпорации добра))

Comment: Давайте не будем забывать о том что для того чтобы замена JS принялась нужно чтобы ее приняли все крупные игроки ;)

Да и JS настолько оптимизирован, что, я твердо убежден в своих словах 

"И даже если бы это происходило, длилось бы это десятилетиями"

Comment: Да. Например в gwt (Google Web Toolkit) Java и Python в клиентской части транслируются в JS.

Появляются также реализации JS для сервера.

Answer (score 1):

Маленькое, узко специализированное, ИМХО:

Когда к node.js будет прикручен WebInspector ( точнее : Network, Scripts, Timeline, Profiles, Audits, Console ) - сие станет огромным толчком к забвению Python ( как web языка ) и PHP

Comment: свято верю в это =)

Answer (score 1):

Логика вещей перемещает пользователя в веб, как следствие появляются такие платформы как Хромбуки, которые вне веба не работают. В пределе они, вполне возможно, займут подавляющую долю рынка ноутбуков и нетбуков. А в таких системах весь пользовательский интерфейс основан на HTML5, то есть JavaScript + HTL + CSS. Поэтому роль JavaScript в будущем будет повышаться.

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас интерпретируемые и исполняемые языки получили очень большое распространения, и во многих вещах по производительности уже не уступают компилированному коду, а в удобстве разработки уже давно его обогнали. Поэтому я думаю что у подобных вещей будущее есть, но вопрос в том смогут ли они продолжать конкурировать с другими схожими технологиями.

Comment: Накопленный объём кодов жив -- значит скоро не помрёт.